# Making a custom message box using tinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm looking to make a three way message box in tkinter. Something like, "do you want chocolate milk, lemonade, or sprite" and then buttons for each of the 3 at the bottom.
As an aside, is it possible to make python "knock out" numbers when counting. So say I'm adding counting from 10 to 60, could I make python skip over every 7 and 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) By message box do you mean something like this?
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Python/GUI-Tk/Creatingasimpledialog.htm

(2)

```
 for i in range(6):
    for j in range(10):
        if j in [7,8]: continue
        print i*10+j
```

prints all numbers 0-59 skipping if it ends in 7 or 8.

Comment: 1) Kind of, I was wanting three buttons on the bottom (chocolate milk, lemonade, sprite), and for sprite to return sprite to the program. 2) That's great, THX

Answer (score 0):

You can use PyMsgBox to do this. Install it with `pip install pymsgbox`. The documentation is at https://pymsgbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

The code to do your example is:

```
>>> import pymsgbox
>>> drink_choice = pymsgbox.confirm('What drink do you want?', 'Title', ['Chocolate milk', 'Lemonade', 'Sprite'])
```